# Printing Python into HTML

Tags: python, html

Hi there? I am wondering if there is any code on how to print the results of a Python Code into HTML. I am trying to find a way to print the result into html.

Comment: I do not have the code since I am not sure how to write it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to integrate python into a webpage, good solutions are [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/). Flask is more focused on simplicity, instead of functionality, while Django has more functionality.

Be sure to read up on their respective documentation.

Comment: Short answer for long story :) +1

Comment: That basically is what I want to do but I am using VI.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the high-level XML API [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html?highlight=elementtree) to generate HTML code:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> html = ET.Element('html')
>>> body = ET.SubElement(html, 'body')
>>> head = ET.SubElement(html, 'head')
>>> title = ET.SubElement(head, 'title')
>>> title.text = "Hello World"
>>> span = ET.SubElement(body, 'span')
>>> span.text = "Hi there"
>>> et = ET.ElementTree(html)
>>> et.write('hello.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you were looking for this : [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/)

Syntax:

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
  <ul>
  {% for user in users %}
    <li><a href="{{ user.url }}">{{ user.username }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Have a nice day.